# Загружаю картинки из интернета, вставляю в imageView. Код написал, результата нет!

Tags: android, android-asynctask, arraylist, imageview

В массиве три картинки(URL), загружаю и вставляю в imageView. Нажимаю на кнопку и ничего не происходит. Разрешение на интернет в манифесте дал. 
Где же косяк. В логе такое,

```
04-02 02:16:23.588 4211-4211/com.example.user.copywork8 E/Zygote: Zygote:  error closing descriptor
                                                              libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
                                                                  at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
                                                                  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:221)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:715)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:651)
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 02:17:07.455 4211-4211/com.example.user.copywork8 E/ffi_jank: timespan = 26.238924
```

код.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
ProgressBar progressBar;
ImageView imageView1, imageView2, imageView3;
ArrayList<String> arrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
    imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img3);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add("http://startandroid.ru/images/stories/pic/android_white.png");
    arrayList.add("http://allboxing.ru/sites/default/files/logo_4.png");
    arrayList.add("http://static.akipress.org/akipress_logo2.png");
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    new MyTask(arrayList);
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Bitmap>> {
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    public MyTask(ArrayList<String> arrayList){
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Bitmap> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String image : arrayList){
            try {
                URL url = new URL(image);
                InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                bitmaps.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return bitmaps;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmaps);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(0));
        imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(1));
        imageView3.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(2));
    }
}
}
```

P.s. Я новичок, прошу без заумных терминов. Если так, то с объяснениями)

Comment: Забыли вызвать `execute` у таска.

Comment: Да, так как использовал конструктор. Так говорил преподователь. Именно нужно вызвать его без execute, вызвав напрямую new MyTasc(arrayList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо запустить задачу после её создания.

- `new MyTask(arrayList).execute();`

или так (запустить задачу из конструктора задачи)

```
public MyTask(ArrayList<String> arrayList){
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    execute();
}
```

Во втором случае полезно сделать MyTask final-классом, поскольку при наследовании от него, таск начнет выполняться до того, как отработает конструктор наследника.

Comment: Большое спасибо, нужен был именно второй вариант) сработало))

Comment: @T.Kudaibergen, добро пожаловать на ru-SO)

Comment: во втором случае нужно хотя бы сделать `MyTask` `final`-классом, поскольку при наследовании от него, таск начнет выполняться до того, как отработает конструктор наследника.

Comment: @zRrr, верно. Добавил это в ответ)